# How to create unique static variables in function pointers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a unique static variable for each function pointer and I need to use a function pointer because I plan on using them inside of a struct.

I tried creating a function pointer to a function with a static variable but it's the same variable in both of them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
  static int test = 10;
  test++;
  printf("%d\n", test);
}

void (*bar)() = foo;

int main()
{
  foo();
  bar();

  return 0;
}
```

I expected this to give me 11 and 11 but I get 11 and 12 so it must increment the same variable twice.

Comment: I believe this is not possible. A function is unaware whether it is called by its name or a pointer pointing to it.

Comment: There isn't a practical way to do it. IThe hypothetical semi-feasible mechanism means you arrange for the functions to take a pointer to a structure which contains the variable to be incremented, and ensure that each 'pointer to function' has associated with it a separate copy of the structure, and that the function call using that pointer passes the structure. So, the structure probably contains the function pointer and the counter, and you pass the structure pointer to the function, which increments the counter. Fiddly! And you must handle calls to the 'plain function' appropriately too.

Comment: Also, if a pointer to function is passed in the argument list to another function, is that a new pointer or the same pointer?  Given that the plain function name is equivalent to a pointer to the function, how does calling the function by name differ from calling via a pointer to function.  (Mostly, therefore, the answer is "No, you can't do it — it doesn't make sense to try to do it".)

Comment: If you plan on using a struct for the function pointers; maybe you should use the struct to store the variables as well and always pass in the struct pointer to each function (ie, like an object in cpp)

Answer (score 1):

This is not something a function pointer can do.

Instead of function pointers, you probably want some kind of object-orientation so you can have several objects each with its own private `test` field, but sharing the same *code*.

For this, you need to go to C++ instead of plain C.

(If for some reason this is not available to you and you *have* to do your stuff in C, there's no real way around giving the function an extra context pointer as a parameter. Or, if you need only finitely many instances of the function, write it several times. They can share a helper function that does the real stuff, but each instance needs to declare their own memory for the helper function to operate on).

Comment: You don't absolutely need C++. All the same things can be done in C, just not as conveniently sometimes. Here you would just need to implement a "this" or "self" for the function, which boils down to the "extra context pointer parameter".

Comment: @aschepler: Correct; that is the point of the last paragraph.